# Problem to resolve Context Injected in BroadcastReceiver using dagger hilt for android

Tags: android, dagger-hilt

I try to inject a class on a BootReceiver (BroadcastReceiver) class and hilt has some issues to resolve the context.
I tried a lot of things and maybe one of you sees what is not correct.
So here is the code example is failing during compile time:

The BootReceiver is defined in AndroidManifest, and will be stated from there:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="ch.didge.flashcaller.BootReceiver" android:enabled="true" 
 android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The class itselfs is defined in BootReceiver.kt

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Inject lateinit var flashCallerRepository: FlashCallerRepository

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.i("BootReceiver", "context: $context intent: $intent")
        context?.let {
          if (flashCallerRepository.getAutostartService()) {
              val i = Intent(context, FlashcallerService::class.java)
              if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                  context.startForegroundService(i)
              } else {
                  context.startService(i)
              }
          }
      } ?: run {
          Log.w("BootReceiver", "Context was null not able to start Service")
      }
  }
}
```

FlashCallerRepository.kt

```
class FlashCallerRepository @Inject constructor( var configurationService: 
    IConfigurationService) {

 
   
    fun getAutostartService(): Boolean {
        return configurationService.getAutostartService()
     }

   
}
```

I want to inject an interface and making the mapping to the implementation here:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
object DiFeatureModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideConfigurationService(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context
    ): IConfigurationService {
        return SharedPreferencesConfigurationService(appContext)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately there is an issue providing the context. I'll using hilt version 2.29.1- alpha.
It seems with my code, hilt is not able to provide the Context (it  should provide the Application Context)
The funny thing is , I'm injecting the same class (FlashCallerRepository) from my Activity class too, and there it does work like a charm.
It seems to be related with the Receiver.

Any Ideas what should be changed?
Thanks a lot!

Luke

Here is the detailed compile stacktrace:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task 
':app:transformClassesWithAndroidEntryPointTransformForFullRelease'.
    at 
org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:205)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:263)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:372)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:359)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:352)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:338)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: onReceive (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V in ch.didge.flashcaller.BootReceiver: failed to resolve types
    at com.android.builder.profile.Recorder$Block.handleException(Recorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:108)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:242)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:104)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskInputsTaskAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.execute(AbstractIncrementalTaskAction.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:553)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:536)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$300(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:276)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:265)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$0(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:32)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:41)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:85)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:94)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:78)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:28)
    at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:192)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: onReceive (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/content/Intent;)V in ch.didge.flashcaller.BootReceiver: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:119)
    at javassist.bytecode.MethodInfo.rebuildStackMap(MethodInfo.java:458)
    at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.AndroidEntryPointClassTransformer.transformOnReceive(AndroidEntryPointClassTransformer.kt:237)
    at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.AndroidEntryPointClassTransformer.transformClass(AndroidEntryPointClassTransformer.kt:134)
    at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.AndroidEntryPointClassTransformer.transformClassToOutput(AndroidEntryPointClassTransformer.kt:106)
    at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.AndroidEntryPointClassTransformer.transformFile(AndroidEntryPointClassTransformer.kt:102)
    at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.AndroidEntryPointTransform.transformFile(AndroidEntryPointTransform.kt:156)
    at dagger.hilt.android.plugin.AndroidEntryPointTransform.transform(AndroidEntryPointTransform.kt:124)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:284)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:247)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:106)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: javassist.bytecode.BadBytecode: failed to resolve types
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:177)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:116)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: javassist.NotFoundException: android.content.Context
    at javassist.ClassPool.get(ClassPool.java:430)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.fixTypes2(TypeData.java:437)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.fixTypes(TypeData.java:410)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.TypeData$TypeVar.dfs(TypeData.java:357)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.fixTypes(MapMaker.java:398)
    at javassist.bytecode.stackmap.MapMaker.make(MapMaker.java:175)
    ... 103 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did found a solution for my situation. Reason is that in my case the BootReceiver seems to be a constellation that won't be supported by hilt, due this BootReceiver will be the starting Point of the Application. In my understanding it should not may a difference, because even then an Application Class object should be created which should ramp up the whole dependency tree.

I hope when hilt is leaving alpha, this scenario will be supported too.
So here I can show you my solution:

```
class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
lateinit var flashCallerRepository: FlashCallerRepository

@EntryPoint
@InstallIn(ApplicationComponent::class)
interface BootReceiverEntryPoint {
    fun getflashCallerRepository(): FlashCallerRepository
}

override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    Log.i("BootReceiver", "context: $context intent: $intent")
    val entryPoint = EntryPointAccessors.fromApplication(context, 
    BootReceiverEntryPoint::class.java)
    flashCallerRepository = entryPoint.getflashCallerRepository()
    context?.let {
         if (flashCallerRepository.getAutostartService()) {
            val i = Intent(context, FlashcallerService::class.java)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                context.startForegroundService(i)
            } else {
                context.startService(i)
            }
         }
        } ?: run {
            Log.w("BootReceiver", "Context was null not able to start Service")
        }
    }
}
```

My expectation is, that once hilt will work in a way, that I'm able to use injection a BootReceiver like already described in my question
above.

**If someone knows how tho handle in a  standard hilt way please let my know.**
At least i was able to solve my situation.

I created an issue in the hilt-project:
[issue in dagger-hilt project](https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2118)